# How to configure the page the / path goes to in a tiny express app?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm using a simple node express server which is wrapped in the Webpack Dev Server (http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

I'm starting an express app from a top level directory where the static files are in a directory called "public".

I've got this line of configuration:

```
server.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

If I type `http://0.0.0.0:3000/index.html`, all is good.

How but the URL of `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` produces a directory listing of the top level.

What is the proper way to configure `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` to go to the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
server.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

See the docs http://devdocs.io/express/index#res.sendFile

Comment: The file is under /public/index.html. I tried: server.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
}); In all cases, I get a directory listing rather than the serving of this file.

Comment: The `app.get` needs to be above `app.use`, otherwise the latter middleware will have priority.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved setting the contentBase proper of the WebpackDevServer plus telling the

server.app.use(express.static(__dirname + contentbase);

Per this diff[image]

The docs are here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html